# Source code about WPF control

Tags: wpf

I want to overwrite ScrollBar, so i want to view its sourcecode. Not ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

Reflector - http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector

But creating your own ScrollBar class won't make other controls use it. The only thing you can do in that case is create a new control template for the existing ScrollBar which you've indicated you don't want to do.

Comment: I want to inherit ScrollBar,So i want to view sourceCode about ScrollBar,How to find its sourcecode.

Answer (score 0):

[JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) is a similar tool to Reflector, but I think you'd be best creating your own ControlTemplate. Is there some specific functionality you need to implement.